# What is a "context bound" in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, context-bound

One of the new features of Scala 2.8 are context bounds. What is a context bound and where is it useful?

Of course I searched first (and found for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961986/how-do-you-write-an-idiomatic-scala-quicksort-function/2962799#2962799)) but I couldn't find any really clear and detailed information.

Comment: also check this out for a tour of all types of bounds: https://gist.github.com/257758/47f06f2f3ca47702b3a86c76a5479d096cb8c7ec

Comment: This excellent answer compares/contrasts context bounds and view bounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/context-and-view-bounds-again/4467012#4467012

Comment: This is a very nice answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25250693/1586965

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Did you find [this article](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/7)?  It covers the new context bound feature, within the context of array improvements.

Generally, a type parameter with a *context bound* is of the form `[T: Bound]`; it is expanded to plain type parameter `T` together with an implicit parameter of type `Bound[T]`.

Consider the method `tabulate` which forms an array from the results of applying
a given function f on a range of numbers from 0 until a given length. Up to Scala 2.7, tabulate could be
written as follows:

```
def tabulate[T](len: Int, f: Int => T) = {
    val xs = new Array[T](len)
    for (i <- 0 until len) xs(i) = f(i)
    xs
}
```

In Scala 2.8 this is no longer possible, because runtime information is necessary to create the right representation of `Array[T]`. One needs to provide this information by passing a `ClassManifest[T]` into the method as an implicit parameter:

```
def tabulate[T](len: Int, f: Int => T)(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]) = {
    val xs = new Array[T](len)
    for (i <- 0 until len) xs(i) = f(i)
    xs
}
```

As a shorthand form, a *context bound* can be used on the type parameter `T` instead, giving:

```
def tabulate[T: ClassManifest](len: Int, f: Int => T) = {
    val xs = new Array[T](len)
    for (i <- 0 until len) xs(i) = f(i)
    xs
}
```

Answer (score 156):

Robert's answer covers the techinal details of Context Bounds. I'll give you my interpretation of their meaning.

In Scala a View Bound (`A <% B`) captures the concept of 'can be seen as' (whereas an upper bound `<:` captures the concept of 'is a'). A context bound (`A : C`) says 'has a' about a type. You can read the examples about manifests as "`T` has a `Manifest`". The example you linked to about `Ordered` vs `Ordering` illustrates the difference. A method

```
def example[T <% Ordered[T]](param: T)
```

says that the parameter can be seen as an `Ordered`. Compare with

```
def example[T : Ordering](param: T)
```

which says that the parameter has an associated `Ordering`.

In terms of use, it took a while for conventions to be established, but context bounds are preferred over view bounds ([view bounds are now deprecated](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629)).  One suggestion is that a context bound is preferred when you need to transfer an implicit definition from one scope to another without needing to refer to it directly (this is certainly the case for the  `ClassManifest` used to create an array).

Another way of thinking about view bounds and context bounds is that the first transfers implicit conversions from the caller's scope. The second transfers implicit objects from the caller's scope.

Comment: "has a" rather than "is a" or "seen as" was the key insight for me - not seen this in any other explanations. Having a plain English version of the otherwise slightly cryptic operators/functions makes it much easier to absorb - thanks!

Comment: @Ben Lings What do you mean by .... **'has a' about a type** ... ? What is **about a type** ?

Comment: @jhegedus Here's my parsing: "about a type" means that A refers to a type.  The phrase "has a" is often used in object-oriented design to describe object relationships (e.g. Customer "has an" Address).  But here the "has a" relationship is between types, not objects.  It's a loose analogy because the "has a" relationship isn't inherent or universal the way it is in OO design; a Customer always has an Address but for the context bound an A doesn't always have a C.  Rather, the context bound specifies that an instance of C[A] must be provided implicitly.

Comment: I have been learning Scala for a month, and this is the best explanation I have seen in this month! Thank you @Ben!

Comment: @Ben Lings: Thanks, after spending so long time to understand what is context bound, your answer is very helpful.[`has a` makes more sense to me]

Answer (score 39):

*(This is a parenthetical note. Read and understand the other answers first.)*

Context Bounds actually generalize View Bounds.

So, given this code expressed with a View Bound:

```
scala> implicit def int2str(i: Int): String = i.toString
int2str: (i: Int)String

scala> def f1[T <% String](t: T) = 0
f1: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: (T) => String)Int
```

This could also be expressed with a Context Bound, with the help of a type alias representing functions from type `F` to type `T`.

```
scala> trait To[T] { type From[F] = F => T }           
defined trait To

scala> def f2[T : To[String]#From](t: T) = 0       
f2: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: (T) => java.lang.String)Int

scala> f2(1)
res1: Int = 0
```

A context bound must be used with a type constructor of kind `* => *`. However the type constructor `Function1` is of kind `(*, *) => *`. The use of the type alias partially applies second type parameter with the type `String`, yielding a type constructor of the correct kind for use as a context bound.

There is a proposal to allow you to directly express partially applied types in Scala, without the use of the type alias inside a trait. You could then write:

```
def f3[T : [X](X => String)](t: T) = 0
```

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of the #From in the definition of f2? I'm not sure where the type F is getting constructed (did I say this correctly?)

Comment: It's called a type projection, referencing a type member `From` of the type `To[String]`. We don't provide a type argument to `From`, so we're refer to the type constructor, not a type. This type constructor is of the right kind to be used as a context bound -- `* -> *`. This bounds the type parameter `T` by requiring an implicit parameter of type `To[String]#From[T]`. Expand the type aliases, and voila, you are left with `Function1[String, T]`.

Comment: should that be Function1[T, String] ?

Answer (score 19):

*This is another parenthetical note.*

As [Ben pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala/2983376#2983376), a context bound represents a "has-a" constraint between a type parameter and a type class.  Put another way, it represents a constraint that an implicit value of a particular type class exists.

When utilizing a context bound, one often needs to surface that implicit value. For example, given the constraint `T : Ordering`, one will often need the instance of `Ordering[T]` that satisfies the constraint.  [As demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373070/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-the-type-class-associated-with-a-context-bound/4373153#4373153), it's possible to access the implicit value by using the `implicitly` method or a slightly more helpful `context` method:

```
def **[T : Numeric](xs: Iterable[T], ys: Iterable[T]) = 
   xs zip ys map { t => implicitly[Numeric[T]].times(t._1, t._2) }
```

or

```
def **[T : Numeric](xs: Iterable[T], ys: Iterable[T]) =
   xs zip ys map { t => context[T]().times(t._1, t._2) }
```