# ":" in type parameter

Tags: scala, context-bound

In scala-arm project, I see code like this:

```
def managed[A : Resource : Manifest](opener : => A) : ManagedResource[A] = new DefaultManagedResource(opener)
```

Can someone explain the meaning of [A : Resource : Manifest] ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
def managed[A : Resource : Manifest](opener : => A) : ManagedResource[A] = new DefaultManagedResource(opener)
```

means

```
def managed[A](opener : => A)(implicit r: Resource[A], m: Manifest[A]) : ManagedResource[A] = new DefaultManagedResource(opener)
```

You can look [link text](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html#context-bounds-and-view-bounds) *7.4 Context Bounds and View Bounds* for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Using a simpler example to illustrate:

```
def method[T : Manifest](param : T) : ResultType[T] = ...
```

The notation `T : Manifest` means that there is a *context bound*.  Elsewhere in your program, in scope, must be defined a singleton or value of type `Manifest[T]` that's marked as an implicit.

This is achieved by the compiler rewriting the method signature to use a second (implicit) parameter block:

```
def method[T](param : T)(implicit x$1 : Manifest[T]) : ResultType[T] = ...
```

As your example illustrates, multiple context bounds can be used in the same method signature.  It's also possible to combine them with view bounds.