# Why does the type parameter bound T <: Comparable[T] fail for T = Int?

Tags: java, scala, scala-2.8

```
scala> class Foo[T <: Comparable[T]](val x : T)
defined class Foo

scala> (3: Int).asInstanceOf[Comparable[Int]]  
res60: java.lang.Comparable[Int] = 3

scala> new Foo(3)                              
<console>:13: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to class Foo's type parameter bounds [T <: java.lang.Comparable[T]]
       new Foo(3)
       ^
```

Is the 2nd expression the result of type erasure?

How would I go about defining Foo so that I could parameterize it with Int but still be able to perform some ordering behavior with its instance variable?

Comment: It's easy to forget (coming from Java) that types like Int and Double are primitives and therefore cannot conform to reference types like Number and Comparable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a [view bound](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130).

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo[T <% Comparable[T]](val x : T)
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(3)
res0: Foo[Int] = Foo@9aca82
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's super helpful and I've been wondering what the <% meant for a while.  So if I understand it correctly, T <% Comparable[T] where T is Int, ensures that there is an implicit conversion from Int to Comparable[Int], and in this case I guess it picks that up from Predef.intWrapper which converts to a RichInt which is Comparable[Int]. I understand it now. I do wish that Scala had a 'debug' mode that would show where / how some of these implicit conversions take place.

Comment: @Collin: `scalac -Xprint:typer myprogram.scala` will show you where implicits got used. Type `scalac -Xshow-phases` to see what other phases there are.

Answer (score 16):

The question, as stated, is still unanswered (though "use view bounds" solves the problem, which is more useful). The answer is simply that an `Int` in Scala is supposed to be equivalent to an `int` in Java, which is not a class at all, and, therefore, cannot even be a `Comparable` (though that *could* be solved in Java 7 with defender methods... I wonder if they'll do it).

The solution given, to use a view bound, is used throughout Scala to solve the problem of a class that could implement something but doesn't, because it is not under Scala's control -- ie, Java classes.

And, of course, it can be used by programmers themselves to deal with similar stuff from libraries and frameworks, or simply to produce wrappers around a library to give it a Scala-ish feeling.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you could use a [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala):

```
class Foo[T: Ordering](val v: T)
```

or

```
class Foo[T: java.util.Comparator](val v: T)
```

The context bound represents an assertion that there is an implicit Ordering[T] (or java.util.Comparator[T]) in scope when the constructor is invoked and is equivalent to adding an implicit parameter:

```
class Foo[T](val v: T)(implicit ev: Ordering[T])
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will allow you to use an alternate ordering based on the context:

```
// by default, new Foo("a", "c", "b").items == List("a", "b", "c")
class Foo[T: Ordering](xs: T*) {
   val items = xs.toList.sorted
}

// with this object in scope, 
// new Foo("a", "c", "b").items == List("c", "b", "a")
implicit val descending = Ordering[String].reverse
```

Comment: I had not understood context bounds until now, and after reading your answer I went off and read further. Very useful and informative. Thanks.