# Type parameter Bounds [T <: Comparable[_]] in guava's MinMaxPriorityQueue in Scala

Tags: scala, guava, comparable, type-bounds

Trying to create a `MinMaxPriorityQueue` using guava's library I am having the following issue:

This works:

```
val q: MinMaxPriorityQueue[String] = MinMaxPriorityQueue.
      maximumSize(10).
      create()
q.add("1.0")
```

But this not:

```
val q: MinMaxPriorityQueue[Double] = MinMaxPriorityQueue.
      maximumSize(10).
      create()
q.add(1.0)
```

As far as I've found while searching [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115218), this may be because Java treats scala's `Double` as a `double` in Java, and it not support `Comparable`. So I've tried this:

```
val q: MinMaxPriorityQueue[Comparable[Double]] = MinMaxPriorityQueue.
      maximumSize(10).
      create()
q.add(1.0)
```

This works, but when I try to add another element:

```
a.add(2.3)
```

it fails:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.RichDouble cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

It seems to be related to the issue mentioned in [1].

I've also tried to write a *Type View*:

```
class Test[A <% Comparable[A]](val q: MinMaxPriorityQueue[A])
val a = new Test[Double](MinMaxPriorityQueue.create())
```

Which gives the same error.

Is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.lang.Double` perhaps?

```
 val q: MinMaxPriorityQueue[java.lang.Double] = ...
```

Should work.