# Scala compiler is complaining about type mismatch for generic parameter on method level

Tags: scala, types, generic-programming, scala-generics

Why Scala compiler cannot compile [next code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OZ53Az3TTk6X3m1cCe9qDw) :

```
trait Profile {}
class SomeProfile extends Profile

trait Foo {
  def get[T <: Profile]: Option[T]
}

object Example {
  val foo: Foo = new Foo {
    // This works (but might give runtime exception), but it is not ugly? :)
    def get[T <: Profile]: Option[T] = Some((new SomeProfile).asInstanceOf[T])
  }

  val foo2: Foo = new Foo {
    // This does not compile with type mismatch :(
    def get[T <: Profile]: Option[T] = Some(new SomeProfile)
  }
}
```

Compiler says:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Playground.this.SomeProfile
 required: T
```

But `SomeProfile` is `T`, no?

## Update:

I want to implement this trait [DatabaseConfigProvider](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/src/core/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/DatabaseConfigProvider.scala#L33) with exact type and do it in this way:

```
val dc: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = ???
val prov = new DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[P <: BasicProfile] = dc.asInstanceOf[DatabaseConfig[P]]
}
```

which looks ugly because of `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: Can you state which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output type of your method `get` is defined by caller. You added type bounds (as `T <: Profile`) but this does only mean limitations for caller. Any casts (as you did) will fail at runtime if caller ask for another subtype of  `Profile` than one you casted.

If you provide more details on what you expect to get as result, I can extend answer with specific advise how to get it.

Comment: I checked implementation and came to SlickApi. And as I see there `asInstanceOf` is actively used. So, suppose that you do not have another choice. The only thing is that there are said that `Usually, you shouldn't need to create instances of `DatabaseConfigProvider` explicitly. Rather, you should rely on dependency injection.` But if you need, looks like you do not have other choice except of `asInstanceOf`

Comment: I need it for integration test where I can define configuration to the database in a code, not in a configuration file. I'm just curious why the compiler is not able to figure it out?

Comment: Figure out what? Output type is generic. Without cast you are trying to return specific type, which is wrong. In other words for method which returns *any child of Profile* (depends on call context), you return specific type.

Comment: Is not this constraint `T <: Profile` (must be a subtype of `Profile` ) respected? Because `SomeProfile` is subtype (implementation) of `Profile` (`class SomeProfile extends Profile`)?

Comment: No. Type bound specify bounds for caller. So, any call by caller as `get[AnyProfileChild]` will be valid. And you return one specific type.

Answer (score 2):

You wrongly declared input argument. Try below:

```
trait Profile {}
class SomeProfile() extends Profile

trait Foo {
  def get[T >: Profile]: Option[T]
}

object Example {
  val foo2: Foo = new Foo {
    override def get[T >: Profile]: Option[T] = Some(new SomeProfile())
  }
}
```

Explanation for what `:>` does, you could find easily in Stackoverflow (e.g.: [What does [B >: A] do in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759361/what-does-b-a-do-in-scala))

Comment: There is no mistake with input argument declaration, I wanted to have `<:` => an upper type bound,

Comment: How you want to use then your get method. If you want declare as  ```val e:Option[Profile] = foo2.get```(with compilation error).