# How does Scalaz `F[_] : Applicative` type constraint imply use of implicit parameters?

Tags: scala, typeclass, scalaz, implicits

I am struggling to understand the following function definition in [`Traverse`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala) trait in Scalaz:

`def traverse[F[_] : Applicative, A, B](f: A => F[B], t: T[A]): F[T[B]]`

The part I don't understand is `F[_] : Applicative`.

Now, let's see what [`Applicative`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala) is:

```
trait Applicative[Z[_]] extends Pointed[Z] with Apply[Z] {
  override def fmap[A, B](fa: Z[A], f: A => B): Z[B] = this(pure(f), fa)
  override def apply[A, B](f: Z[A => B], a: Z[A]): Z[B] = liftA2(f, a, (_:A => B)(_: A))
  def liftA2[A, B, C](a: Z[A], b: Z[B], f: (A, B) => C): Z[C] = apply(fmap(a, f.curried), b)
}
```

Here, for `traverse` to work for some type `F`, one needs to bring an implicit object of type `Applicative[F]` in scope.

I'd like to understand several things:

1. Wat exactly does `F[_] : Applicative` mean?
2. Why does `F[_]` has something to do with `Applicative`? We need `Applicative[F]`, not F[something] extends Applicative right?
3. Why does this method use implicit values of type `Applicative[F]` without declaring implicit parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all three questions can be answered with the fact that this notation:

```
def traverse[F[_] : Applicative, A, B](f: A => F[B], t: T[A]): F[T[B]]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
def traverse[F[_], A, B](f: A => F[B], t: T[A])(implicit $ev: Applicative[F]): F[T[B]]
```

The first notation is known as a [*context bound*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala) for `F[_]`.

Comment: Aha, so this **is** a special language feature! Thank you!