# How can I define a method that takes an Ordered[T] Array in Scala?

Tags: algorithm, generics, scala

I'm building some basic algorithms in Scala (following Cormen's book) to refresh my mind on the subject and I'm building the **insertion sort** algorithm. Doing it like this, it works correctly:

```
class InsertionSort extends Sort {

def sort ( items : Array[Int] ) : Unit = {

    if ( items.length < 2 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Array must be bigger than 1" )
    }

    1.until( items.length ).foreach( ( currentIndex ) => {

        val key = items(currentIndex)

        var loopIndex = currentIndex - 1

        while ( loopIndex > -1 && items(loopIndex) > key ) {

            items.update( loopIndex + 1, items(loopIndex) )

            loopIndex -= 1
        }

        items.update( loopIndex + 1, key )

    } )

}

}
```

But this is for **Int** only and I would like to use generics and **Ordered[A]** so I could sort any type that is ordered. When I change the signature to be like this:

```
def sort( items : Array[Ordered[_]] ) : Unit
```

The following spec doesn't compile:

```
"sort correctly with merge sort" in {

  val items = Array[RichInt](5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3)

  insertionSort.sort( items )

  items.toList === Array[RichInt]( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ).toList

}
```

And the compiler error is:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Array[Ordered[_]], actual Array[RichInt]
```

But isn't RichInt an Ordered[RichInt]? How should I define this method signature in a way that it would accept any Ordered object?

**EDIT**

In case anyone is interested, the final source is available [here](https://github.com/mauricio/introduction-to-algorithms).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually `RichInt` is not an `Ordered[RichInt]` but an `Ordered[Int]`. However `scala.runtime.RichInt <: Ordered[_]`, but class `Array` is invariant in type `T` so `Array[RichInt]` is not an `Array[Ordered[_]]`.

```
scala> def f[T <% Ordered[T]](arr: Array[T]) = { arr(0) < arr(1) }
f: [T](arr: Array[T])(implicit evidence$1: T => Ordered[T])Boolean

scala> f(Array(1,2,3))
res2: Boolean = true

scala>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a [*context bound*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala) on the type parameter;

```
scala> def foo[T : Ordering](arr: Array[T]) = { 
    |    import math.Ordering.Implicits._ 
    |    arr(0) < arr(1) 
    |  }
foo: [T](arr: Array[T])(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[T])Boolean
```

Such that usage is:

```
scala> foo(Array(2.3, 3.4))
res1: Boolean = true
```

The advantage to this is that you don't need the default order of the type if you don't want it:

```
scala> foo(Array("z", "bc"))
res4: Boolean = false

scala> foo(Array("z", "bc"))(Ordering.by(_.length))
res3: Boolean = true
```