# Unclear Scala manifest syntax

Tags: scala, syntax, manifest

I saw a piece of Scala code with manifest syntax as follows. I do not know what WireFormat means here. What constraint does it add to the Manifest A? Does it mean the type A must extends the trait WireFormat?

I could not find any document about such syntax.

```
trait WireFormat[A] {
  def toWire(x: A, out: DataOutput)
  def fromWire(in: DataInput): A
}

class DList[A : Manifest : WireFormat]
```

Comment: Read it as _takes an `A` such that there's a `Manifest` and a `WireFormat` context for `A`_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [*context bound*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala). With two types separated by colons it just means there are two implicit parameters.

In other words it's the same as:

```
class DList[A](implicit x: Manifest[A], y: WireFormat[A])
```

Comment: On [context bounds and view bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds) is also very handy.