# Scala function that sorts a Seq using the mapping of a generic function

Tags: scala, sorting, mapping

I'm trying to write a function that maps a sequence S by a function F (I'll call it F(S)), zips the resulting values (F(S)) with S, and sorts the result by F(S), returning the sorted zipped values (I hope the code clears this up, it's difficult to put into text)

Here's my current code:

```
def sortByAndReturnZippedMetric[S,M<:Ordering[AnyVal]]( s:Seq[S], mapper:S=>M):Seq[(M,S)] =
s.map(mapper).zip(s).sortBy(_._1)
```

Scalac is complaining, though:

```
error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[M]
starting with method comparatorToOrdering in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits
s.map(mapper).zip(s).sortBy(_._1)

                               ^
```

I'd appreciate some pointers as to what might be wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ordering` is a [type class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), which means that if you want to capture the fact that `A` is ordered in a particular way, you simply put an implicit instance of `Ordering[A]` into scope—you don't have `A` extend `Ordering[A]` (or `Ordering[AnyVal]`, etc.).

The advantage of this approach is that you can work with multiple orderings for a particular type (although only one implicit ordering can be in scope at a time for a type). So for example I can write the following:

```
scala> List(5, 2, 3, 1, 4).sorted
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Here the implicit ordering for integers (`Ordering.Int`) is used as the implicit argument to `sorted`, but we could also explicitly pass a different `Ordering`. For example, we could create a new ordering by reversing the implicit one:

```
scala> List(5, 2, 3, 1, 4).sorted(Ordering.Int.reverse)
res1: List[Int] = List(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

In your case `sortBy` is looking for an `Ordering[Ordering[AnyVal]]`, which doesn't exist. You can easily fix this by using a [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2982276/334519) to indicate that you need an ordering for `M`, instead of having `M` extend `Ordering[AnyVal]`:

```
def sortByZipped[S, M: Ordering](s: Seq[S], mapper: S => M): Seq[(M, S)] =
  s.map(mapper).zip(s).sortBy(_._1)
```

Or you can skip the syntactic sugar and use an implicit argument:

```
def sortByZipped[S, M](s: Seq[S], mapper: S => M)(implicit o: Ordering[M]) =
  s.map(mapper).zip(s).sortBy(_._1)(o)
```

This is exactly equivalent to the version with the context bound.

Comment: whoosh! There's a lot going on here I was not aware of, but your answer is thoroughly well explained and documented, so it's only a matter of time. This is truly gold - thank you for making me aware of what I didn't know!