# What is this type A in learning Scalaz for the sum function?

Tags: scala, scalaz

In [Learning Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/sum+function.html) there is a type parameter on the method sum.

Does this mean that the type A is of type Monoid? However that seems wrong, if the type A is a Monoid then how can it also be an integer as it is used in the example. I must be reading the type parameter wrong.

What is the meaning of the type parameter? How should I be reading it?

```
def sum[A: Monoid](xs: List[A]): A = {
     val m = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
     xs.foldLeft(m.mzero)(m.mappend)
   }
```

Comment: This feature is called: [context bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala). It can be read as: "for the type `A`, there must be an implicit value of type `Monoid[A]`". The `implicitly` call gets that implicit value.

Comment: Why did they write it as `A: Monoid`? it seems backwards.

Comment: Try reading the whole thing as: "the method `sum` has a type parameter `A`, for which there must be a `Monoid`".

Comment: It seems very inconsistent with other notation.

Comment: If you want to know "why this syntax", I don't know, that's just how the Scala language designers chose it. Why exactly do you think it is inconsistent? Do you have an alternative idea that looks more consistent to you?

Comment: I mean that when I first say this I see a `A: Monoid` and my first interpretation of this is that A is of type Monoid, whenever I see a : with something on the left and something on the right, I assume the type of the left is on the right.

Comment: I don't have a better idea, I just wanted to say how I saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A: Monoid` is a type parameter with a [Context Bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala). It's syntactic sugar.

The following:

```
def sum[A: Monoid](xs: List[A]): A
```

gets desugared into:

```
def sum[A](xs: List[A])(implicit val $ev: Monoid[A]): A
```

Comment: Why that syntax? A: Monoid, how would you describe that in English, its "implicit Monoid of type A"?