# What is the colon in the type parameter of a scala class

Tags: class, scala, generics

I know when a class is parameterized, it could be declared as

```
class A[T]
```

I see declaration of RDD of Spark begins with:

```
abstract class RDD[T: ClassTag]
```

I don't know what does the `: ClassTag` mean.

Comment: Actually, colon means "context bound", ClassTag is a part of new scala reflection and you can easily get to know it on scala website, this is RTFM question (you may search on SO, plenty of questions): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala, http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Comment: Thanks. I never know this syntax is called context view. I found an comprehensive explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds/4467012#4467012

Answer (score 5):

This is a syntactic variant for writing

```
abstract class RDD[T](implicit context: ClassTag[T])
```

The comments to this question already link to two related questions that explain what this so-called 'context bound' is about.