# When do you have to include the abstract type parameter?

Tags: scala

Here's two piece of example code, found [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors):

```
scala> val im = m.reflect(new C)
im: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for C@3442299e
```

and [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag):

```
scala> def mkArray[T : ClassTag](elems: T*) = Array[T](elems: _*)
```

the first piece of code uses a method defined in scala.reflect.api.Mirrors (found [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors$ReflectiveMirror)):

```
abstract def reflect[T](obj: T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Universe.InstanceMirror
```

if you notice, there's a `ClassTag` used like `ClassTag[T]` and one used like `ClassTag`.  What's the reason for the difference?

Comment: `[T : ClassTag]` is synthactic sugar for the other: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, both are equivalent.

```
foo[T: ClassTag]()
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
 foo[T]()(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]
```

*However*, the difference between these signatures is that in the former, you have to access the `ClassTag` via `implicitly[ClassTag[T]]` while in the latter, you can just use `ct`

**Syntax change note:** 
Before 2.10.x it used to not be possible to have have both a *context bound* like `ClassTag` and an `implicit` argument list, such as:

```
foo[T: ClassTag]()(implicit ex: ExecutionContext)
```

The error used to be reported as *"Error: cannot have both implicit parameters and context bounds"*. IntelliJ 13 was still reporting it as late as 2.10.4, but is now accepted by the scala compiler.

Comment: The second statement isn't true. The compiler will place the context-bound arguments before the other implicit parameters. `foo[T: ClassTag]()(implicit ex: ExecutionContext)` becomes `foo[T]()(implicit evidence$1: ClassTag[T], ex: ExecutionContext)`

Comment: Interesting this must be a left over from a previous version of scala. Used to get `cannot have both implicit parameters and context 
bounds` and IntelliJ 13 still reports this in its syntax parser with 2.10.4. But sbt is happy with the syntax

Comment: Appears to be fixed in 14: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6989. I believe this was added in Scala 2.10.