# Scala type boundary and context type combined shorthand form

Tags: scala

I bumped into code using this syntax:

```
def foo[T <: A: B]
```

What kind of constraint does B add to the definition?

Answer (score 6):

There are two separate parts to the constraint, represented in that shorthand form:

1. `T <: A` (which means that `T` must be a subtype of `A`).
2. `T : B` a [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2983376/1509695) which means `B[T]` is required implicitly.

Context bounds are a syntactic sugar. Desugared, the function signature looks like this:

```
def foo[T <: A](implicit param: B[T])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "context bound", see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala) for a detailed description