# Defining Type Parameter That's a Sub-class & Implements 2 Traits

Tags: scala

Given a few traits:

```
scala> sealed trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> sealed trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case class Kid(name: String) extends Parent
defined class Kid

scala> sealed trait HasNickname
defined trait HasNickname
```

I attempted to define a method that takes an `A` that satisfies:

- sub-class of `Parent`
- implements trait `HasNickname`
- implements trait `Foo`

But I got a compile-time error:

```
scala> def f[A <: Parent : Foo with HasNickname](x: A): A = ???
<console>:14: error: Foo with HasNickname does not take type parameters
       def f[A <: Parent : Foo with HasNickname](x: A): A = ???
                         ^
```

How can I modify `f` to fit the above criteria?

Comment: Actually, I think that `def f[A <: Parent with Foo with HasNickname](x: A): A = ???` will work.

Comment: Indeed. The single `:` in the type parameters is used for [context bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala).