# Scala mock function with implicit generic types

Tags: scala, scalamock

I'm trying to mock Cassandra `ScalaGettableData` object using scalamock. I need to mock the following method:

```
def getMap[K : TypeConverter, V : TypeConverter](name: String) = get[Map[K, V]](name)
```

`TypeConverter` is a `Trait` and has implicit implementations such as:

`implicit object StringConverter extends TypeConverter[String]`

In my code I'm calling

`scalaGettableData.getMap[String, String]("myMap")`

and I guess it's implicitly converted to

`scalaGettableData.getMap[StringConverter, StringConverter]("myMap")`

My Test code is as following :

```
val cassandraRow1 = mock[ScalaGettableData]
(cassandraRow1.getMap[String, String] _).expects("localizations_config").returning(Map("key1" -> "value1"))`
```

But I'm getting compilation error:

```
Error:(28, 26) _ must follow method; cannot follow (name: String)(implicit evidence$3: com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter[String], implicit evidence$4: com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter[String])Map[String,String] <and> (index: Int)(implicit evidence$3: com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter[String], implicit evidence$4: com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter[String])Map[String,String]
```

How am I supposed to mock this method ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2983376/411944 on how context bounds work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this example helps:

```
"implicit parameters" should "be mockable" in {
  trait Bar[T]
  trait Foo {
    def getMap[K : Bar](name: String): Int
  }

  val m = mock[Foo]
  (m.getMap[Long](_: String)(_: Bar[Long])) expects(*, *) returning 42 once()

  implicit val b = new Bar[Long] {}
  m.getMap("bar")
}
```

Effectively, the type parameter `K : Bar` gets converted by the Scala compiler to a second parameter list, which is mocked out explicitely in this example with `(_: Bar[Long])`.

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you can improve the quality of your answer by explaining why or how the code works. Sort of a `teach a man to fish` thing.

Comment: :) Have 10 points. When replying to someone besides the author of the exact post (question or answer), make sure to tag them like  @Username, there's even an auto-complete of participating users.