# scala-cass generic read from cassandra table as case class

Tags: scala, cassandra, type-constraints, scala-generics

I am attempting to use [scala-cass](http://thurstonsand.github.io/scala-cass/) in order to read from cassandra and convert the resultset to a case class using `resultSet.as[CaseClass]`. This works great when running the following.

```
import com.weather.scalacass.syntax._    
case class TestTable(id: String, data1: Int, data2: Long)
val resultSet = session.execute(s"select * from test.testTable limit 10")
resultSet.one.as[TestTable]
```

Now I am attempting to make this more generic and I am unable to find the proper type constraint for the generic class.

```
import com.weather.scalacass.syntax._    
case class TestTable(id: String, data1: Int, data2: Long)

abstract class GenericReader[T] {
  val table: String
  val keyspace: String

  def getRows(session: Session): T = {
    val resultSet = session.execute(s"select * from $keyspace.$table limit 10")
    resultSet.one.as[T]
  }
}
```

I implement this class with the desired case class and attempt to call getRows on the created Object.

```
object TestTable extends GenericReader[TestTable] {
  val keyspace = "test"
  val table = "TestTable"
}

TestTable.getRows(session)
```

This throws an exception `could not find implicit value for parameter ccd: com.weather.scalacass.CCCassFormatDecoder[T]`.

I am trying to add a type constraint to GenericReader in order to ensure the implicit conversion will work. However, I am unable to find the proper type. I am attempting to read through scala-cass in order to find the proper constraint but I have had no luck so far.

I would also be happy to use any other library that can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `as[T]` requires an implicit value that you don't have in scope, so you'll need to require that implicit parameter in the `getRows` method as well.

```
def getRows(session: Session)(implicit cfd: CCCassFormatDecoder[T]): T
```

You could express this as a type constraint (what you were looking for in the original question) using [context bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala):

```
abstract class GenericReader[T:CCCassFormatDecoder]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to bound your generic `T` type, it might be easier to just pass through the missing implicit parameter:

```
abstract class GenericReader[T](implicit ccd: CCCassFormatDecoder[T]) {
  val table: String
  val keyspace: String

  def getRows(session: Session): T = {
    val resultSet = session.execute(s"select * from $keyspace.$table limit 10")
    resultSet.one.as[T]
  }
}
```

Finding a concrete value for that implicit can then be deferred to when you narrow that `T` to a specific class (like `object TestTable extends GenericReader[TestTable]`)