# How to define an implicit deserializer using Play Json for generic types

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have a method accepting T and I'd like to do `Json.parse(someString).as[T]`.

Now the T classes that I pass in have implicit formats defined such as `implicit lazy val format: Format[Foo] = ...`. However, I'd like to be able to tell the compiler to find the implicit formats at runtime instead of complaining "No Json deserializer found for type T".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to add a [context bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala) on `T`:

```
def yourMethod[T: Reads](...) = ...
```

It won't be looking for the implicits at runtime (which Scala can't do), but won't let you call the method if there is no implicit like `format` available in scope. And when there is, it'll just pass it through to `as` and any other methods which need it.

If your method needs to serialize as well as serialize, you'll need both bounds: `T: Reads: Writes` or just `T: Format`.

Comment: Thanks. I also had to add a TypeTag context bound for some special case handling of types only in my case, but the answer worked perfectly.