# Trying to understand ClassTag and TypeTag in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand how we can overcome type erasure in scala using `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`. I wrote the following examples which are generic functions that try to filter out `List[TNode]` where `TNode` is equal to `TMatch`. However, I expect in `recognizeUsingTypeTag`, the function shall not call  `extractUsingClassTag` is the generic type of list is equal to `TMatch` (or the message gets printed), but my assumption is apparently wrong. Thank you.

```
object Extractor {
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag

  def extractFail[TNode, TMatch](list: List[TNode]) = list.filter {
    case _: TMatch => true
    case _ => false
  }.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[TMatch])

  def extractUsingClassTag[TNode, TMatch](list: List[TNode])(implicit tag1: ClassTag[TNode], tag2: ClassTag[TMatch]) = list.filter {
    case _: TMatch => true
    case _ => false
  }.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[TMatch])

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def recognizeUsingTypeTag[TNode, TMatch](list: List[TNode])(implicit tag1: TypeTag[TNode], tag2: TypeTag[TMatch], tag3: ClassTag[TNode], tag4: ClassTag[TMatch]) = list match {
    case _ if typeOf[TNode] =:= typeOf[TMatch] => {
      //
      // Why this does not get printed for List[String]
      //
      println("This should get printed when called for homogeneous")
      list.asInstanceOf[List[TMatch]]
    }
    case _ => extractUsingClassTag[TNode, TMatch](list)
  }
}

val homogeneous: List[String] = List("Hello", "World!")
val heterogeneous: List[Any] = List("Hello", "World!", 123, false)

println("extractFail")
println(Extractor.extractFail[Any, String](homogeneous))
println(Extractor.extractFail[Any, String](heterogeneous) + "\n")

println("extractUsingClassTag")
println(Extractor.extractUsingClassTag[Any, String](homogeneous))
println(Extractor.extractUsingClassTag[Any, String](heterogeneous) + "\n")

println("recognizeUsingTypeTag")
println(Extractor.recognizeUsingTypeTag[Any, String](homogeneous))
println(Extractor.recognizeUsingTypeTag[Any, String](heterogeneous) + "\n")
```

Console:

```
extractFail
List(Hello, World!)
List(Hello, World!, 123, false)

extractUsingClassTag
List(Hello, World!)
List(Hello, World!)

recognizeUsingTypeTag
List(Hello, World!)
List(Hello, World!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this does not get printed for List[String]

Because you specified explicit type parameters: `[Any, String]`, so `case _ if typeOf[TNode] =:= typeOf[TMatch]` compares `typeOf[Any] =:= typeOf[String]`.

Since you do need to specify `String` for `TMatch`, but want `TNode` to be inferred, the usual way to do it is splitting type parameters into two lists by creating an intermediate class:

```
// in Extractor
class RecognizeUsingTypeTag[TMatch : TypeTag : ClassTag] {
  def apply[TNode : TypeTag : ClassTag](list: List[TNode]) = list match {
    case _ if typeOf[TNode] =:= typeOf[TMatch] => {
      //
      // Why this does not get printed for List[String]
      //
      println("This should get printed when called for homogeneous")
      list.asInstanceOf[List[TMatch]]
    }
    case _ => extractUsingClassTag[TNode, TMatch](list)
  }
}

def recognizeUsingTypeTag[TMatch : TypeTag : ClassTag] = new RecognizeUsingTypeTag[TMatch]


println(Extractor.recognizeUsingTypeTag[String].apply(homogeneous)) // inferred as apply[String]
println(Extractor.recognizeUsingTypeTag[String].apply(heterogeneous) + "\n") // inferred as apply[Any]
```

When you have implicit parameters like that *and don't need their names*, it's preferred to use [context bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala): `T : TypeTag : ClassTag` adds two implicit parameters of types `TypeTag[T]` and `ClassTag[T]`.

Comment: I am getting a compile error. I think those implicit parameters for the `apply` methods need to be specified beside the method generic types, not beside the `List[TNode]`

Comment: @Node.JS Yes, fixed.