# Difference between normal parameter T and T:Manifest

Tags: scala, types, manifest

I am trying to understand the difference between 2 different pieces of code. What is the difference between `T:Manifest` and `T`?

I read about the manifests but didn't totally get it.

```scala
abstract class Def[+T]{
}

def findDefinition[T](d: Def[T]) ={
      //some code
}

def findDefinition[T:Manifest](d: Def[T]) = {
     //some code
}
```

Comment: Manifests are deprecated, so now it should be `[T: TypeTag]` https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Comment: `[T:Manifest]` : `T` is "context bound" to `Manifest[T]`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2982276/4993128).