# Difference between [A: C] and [A[_]: C] context bounds

Tags: scala, implicit, higher-kinded-types, type-constructor, context-bound

I'm a newbie, according to my lectures : 
`class Test [T: Comparing]` means that it requires an implicit value of type `Comparing[T]` that can be used in the methods of that class.
With this Higher kinded type notation

Question : What does this expression `def notation[F[_]: Sync] : F[Unit] = ???`  refer to ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982276/what-is-a-context-bound-in-scala

Comment: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/sync.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the difference between concrete type and type *constructor*

```
Int         // concrete type
List[Int]   // concrete type
List        // type constructor
```

We represent the shape of the type constructor using notation `F[_]`

```
trait Foo[T]            // Foo takes any type
trait Bar[F[_]]         // Bar takes any type constructor

new Foo[Int] {}         // ok
new Foo[List[Int]] {}   // ok
new Foo[List] {}        // error

new Bar[Int] {}         // error
new Bar[List[Int]] {}   // error 
new Bar[List] {}        // ok
```

We could read type parameter clause `[F[_]: Bar]` as meaning

- method requires implicit value of type `Bar[F]` where `F` is a type constructor
- type constructor `F` has to be a [member](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes/#type-classes-to-the-rescue) of the typeclass `Bar`

```
trait Bar[F[_]]

// make type constructor Foo a member of typeclass Bar
implicit val barOfFoo: Bar[Foo] = new Bar[Foo] { println("woohoo") }

def g[F[_]: Bar] = implicitly[Bar[F]]

g[Foo]        // ok
g[Int]        // error - type parameter is of incorrect shape
g[Foo[Int]]   // error - type parameter is of incorrect shape
g[List]       // error - type parameter is of correct shape but not a member of Bar
```

Applying the above concepts to `def notation[F[_]: Sync]` we see that type constructor `F` has to be a member of typeclass `Sync` in order to call `notation`.

Comment: interesting - g[Foo[Int]] isn't caught by intellij's scala plugin (in the latest EAP version, at least).

Comment: @mtk It seems to be a bug with editor type-aware highlighting. Metals highlights it correctly.