# QuickSort Traditional vs Functional Style What Causes This Difference?

Tags: scala

I am comparing two codes written in scala language.

```
package chapter01

object QuickSortScalaTime {
  def sortFunctional(xs: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    if (xs.length <= 1) xs
    else {
      val pivot = xs(xs.length / 2)
      Array.concat(sortFunctional(xs filter (pivot >)), xs filter (pivot ==), sortFunctional(xs filter (pivot <)))
    }
  }

  def sortTraditionl(xs: Array[Int]) {
    def swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
      val t = xs(i);
      xs(i) = xs(j);
      xs(j) = t;
    }

    def sort1(l: Int, r: Int) {
      val pivot = xs((l + r) / 2)
      var i = l;
      var j = r;
      while (i <= j) {
        while (xs(i) < pivot) i += 1
        while (xs(j) > pivot) j -= 1
        if (i <= j) {
          swap(i, j)
          i += 1
          j -= 1
        }
      }
      if (l < j) sort1(l, j)
      if (j < r) sort1(i, r)
    }
    sort1(0, xs.length - 1)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val arr = Array.fill(100000) { scala.util.Random.nextInt(100000 - 1) }
    var t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
    sortFunctional(arr)
    var t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
    println("Functional style : " + (t2-t1))

    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis
    sortTraditionl(arr)
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis
    println("Traditional style : " + (t2-t1))
  }

}
```

The first block is written in functional style and the second block is traditional quick sort. The examples are from Odersky's book by the way.

There is a huge difference between traditional and functional.

```
Functional style : 450
Traditional style : 30
```

I just wonder what causes this difference. I do not know scala in depth but my initial guess is the traditional one uses no mutation and any closures. And what can we do to improve the performance of functional style ?

Comment: It is completely acceptable in scala to use mutable state locally to make things quicker. Martin Odersky himself suggested this in his keynote of the 2013 scala days http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkTFx3-duc8 . So in the real world your sortFunctional method would create a copy of the array to be sorted and use normal in-place quicksort internally. As long as the mutable state remains confined to a local method it is pretty harmless.

Comment: Be aware that your test does not force the Java runtime to compile the code first, so little can be made of those times.  Still, I would expect an in-place sort to be much faster, and since sorting large datasets is very time-consuming it is often a target for optimization. Of course, it has already been done for you in the std library:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Sorting$
For more on performance see https://nicholassterling.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/scala-performance/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's mentioned in the book:

> Both the imperative and the functional implementation have the same
>   asymptotic complexity – O(N log(N)) in the average case and O(N2) in
>   the worst case. But where the imperative implementation operates in
>   place by modifying the argument array, the functional implementation
>   returns a new sorted array and leaves the argument array unchanged.
>   The functional implementation thus requires more transient memory
>   than the imperative one.

The traditional operates in-place on the original array, so no copies are done and no additional memory is needed. The functional one allocates a new array and copies a lot of data on each call.

Answer (score 11):

Well, your functional sort is a bit wrong. It works, but it calls `xs.filter` three times! So in every call you traverse the list three times, instead of one.

Consider this implementation:

```
def sort(ls: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  ls match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case pivot :: tail => {
      val (less, greater) = tail.partition(_ < pivot)
      sort(less) ::: pivot :: sort(greater)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure it would give you the desired performance, but it avoids unnecessary traversals of the list.

More, you may read the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962799/1472049) for an implementation that uses the `foldLeft`

Comment: I wonder how you can do this kinda optimization if you actually pick a pivot at random instead picking the first element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know scala but functional one probably rebuilds the array each time you call it. Each sortFunctional returns a new array which is concatted using Array.concat which creates a new array.

sortTraditionl does not have this overhead, it edits the content of array inplace

Answer (score 0):

Insted of flitering three times, as was done in the scala program with the functional sort, we can divide it by going through the list once as shown in the algorithm below.

```
def quickSort(input: List[Int]): List[Int] = {

/**
 * This method divides the given list into three sublists
 * using a random pivot.
 * (less than pivot, equal to pivot, greater than pivot)
 *
 * @param list
 * @return
 */
def pivot(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  val randomPivot = list(new Random().nextInt(input.length))

  list.foldLeft(List[Int](), List[Int](), List[Int]())( (acc, element) => {
    val (lessThanPivot, equalToPivot, greaterThanPivot) = acc

    element match {
      case x if x < randomPivot => (x :: lessThanPivot, equalToPivot, greaterThanPivot)
      case x if x > randomPivot => (lessThanPivot,      equalToPivot, x :: greaterThanPivot)
      case x @ _                => (lessThanPivot,  x ::equalToPivot, greaterThanPivot)
    }
  })
}

input match {

  case Nil => Nil
  case oneElementList @ List(x) => oneElementList
  case head :: tail => {

    val (lessThanPivot, equalToPivot, greaterThanPivot) = pivot(input)

    //step 2 & 3
    quickSort(lessThanPivot) :::
      equalToPivot           :::
      quickSort(greaterThanPivot)

  }
}
```

The code can also be found in the [github](https://github.com/ChandraAddala/functional-programming-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/examples/NestedLoops.scala#L63) repo.