# Scala - Remove while loop in quick sort

Tags: scala, functional-programming, quicksort

```
def QuickSort(arr:Array[Int],first:Int,last:Int): List[Int] = {
    var pivot:Int = 0
    var temp:Int = 0
    if (first < last) {
        pivot = first
        var i:Int = first
        var j:Int = last;
        while(i<j){
            while(arr(i) <= arr(pivot) && i < last)
                i=i+1
            while(arr(j) > arr(pivot))
                j=j+1
            if(i<j)
            {
                temp = arr(i)
                arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            }
        }
        temp = arr(pivot)
        arr(pivot) = arr(j)
        arr(j) = temp
        QuickSort(arr, first, j-1)
        QuickSort(arr, j+1, last)
    }
    arr.toList
  }
```

Hello I m new to scala and trying to implement **quick sort**. Program is working correctly but I want to **remove the while loop** since I read that while and do while are not recommended in scala because they do not return any value.

Is there any way to remove while loop in above code.

Comment: So do you want to return a value from the loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [classic quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm, as you've coded here, requires a mutable collection (like `Array`) and the swapping of element values, which requires mutable variables (i.e. `var`).  These things are discouraged in functional programming and aren't held in high esteem in the Scala community.

Here's a similar approach that is a little more in keeping to the spirit of the FP ethic.

```
// pseudo-quicksort -- from Array[Int] to List[Int]
def pqs(arr:Array[Int]): List[Int] = arr match {
  case Array()    => List()
  case Array(x)   => List(x)
  case Array(x,y) => if (x < y) List(x,y) else List(y,x)
  case _ => val (below, above) = arr.partition(_ < arr(0))
            pqs(below) ++ List(arr(0)) ++ pqs(above.tail)
}
```

Better yet is to use one of the sort methods (`sortBy`, `sortWith`, `sorted`) as offered in the standard library.

Comment: There is an implementation that is simpler here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20880933/5123895

Answer (score 2):

Not so elegant, but without while:

```
  def QuickSort(l: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    if( l.length == 0) return Nil
    if( l.length == 1 ) return arr
    val pivot = arr(arr.length / 2)
    val lesserThanPivot = l.filter( _ < pivot)
    val equalToPivot = l.filter( _ == pivot)
    val biggerThanPivot = l.filter( _ > pivot)

    QuickSort( lesserThanPivot ) ++ equalToPivot.tail ++ List(pivot) ++ QuickSort(biggerThanPivot)  

  }
```

Comment: You should replace those `return`s whit `else`s.