# String Length() Trouble Performance

Tags: java

From the Code for String class I can see that `length()` returns `value.length` [(here)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java).

Lets say I want to print the length of a string `str` `length()` number of times.

Q1) What would be the better way to do it from the following code snippets: (if you have a better method please suggest)

**Code 1:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String str="Hello World";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();++i){
            System.out.println(str.length());
        }        
}
```

**Code 2** (I prefer this one cause of the readability it offers about the program...)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String str="Hello World";
        final int len=str.length();
        for(int i=0;i<len;++i){
            System.out.println(len);
        }        
    }
```

**Code 3:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String str="Hello World";
        int len=str.length();
        for(int i=0;i<len;++i){
            System.out.println(len);
        }        
    }
```

Q2) Which is the most optimized way OR are they the same ?

Q3) Does the compiler inline the length in the bytecode generated for this program ?

Thanks!

Comment: For a small program like this, you could compile the program and look at the bytecode. Follow along with the wiki article for byte code instructions. The JVM is a different story.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do... why would you want to print out the length of `str` 11 times?

Comment: The time it takes to call `length()` is negligible compared to the time it takes to print out the result.

Comment: Something tells me I am not good at asking questions :|

Comment: @boxed__l No, its just that this isn't a very good question itself. Using correct formatting and all that does not make a question good. (Plus, this question shows you did absolutely no research - you need to at least google it first.)

Comment: @StormeHawke : The code was intended to replace any trivial task..Main focus on length() vs assigning length() to a variable (micro optimizations as Oscar Lopez pointed out)

Comment: Just follow these simple rules:
The First Rule of Program Optimization: *Don't do it*.  
The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): *Don't do it yet*.

Comment: @VeriTi Well, that depends on what you are optimizing on the program. You should be optimizing for readability and reusability, not for speed.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725428/going-back-to-the-first-index-after-reaching-the-last-one-in-an-array) and tell me whether the point made by luis.espional is correct...(in comments section)

Comment: @AJMansfield and this is called *refactoring*, and usually is opposite for optimization, isn't it?

Comment: @boxed__l The two are somewhat different, in that by factoring out the `length()` call, you are allowing the compiler to replace the modulus division with parallel indexes, which it will. Here, factoring out the `length()` call will only eliminate one subtraction operation, which is not even nearly as intensive as a division.  (They really shouldn't be doing it either, without actual performance tests showing it's necessary.)

Comment: @AJMansfield : What do you mean by `modulus division with parallel indexes` ?

Comment: What I mean, is that instead of the compiler putting a modulus division instruction there, it will convert the code into doing something like the accepted answer's first two snippets.

Comment: @AJMansfield : I want to clarify that this question was directed towards that link(Framing of this question was totally wrong). I should have profiled it(as pointed by Oscar Lopez) first before asking here :P thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the suggested snippets are micro-optimizations, and won't yield a noticeable performance improvement. For what is worth, here's yet another option...

```
final String str = "Hello World";
for (int i = 0, n = str.length(); i < n; ++i) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

What are the differences? that `n` is defined on the scope of the block where it's used, that `++i` *might* be faster (this is open to discussion, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561588/what-is-more-efficient-i-or-i)) and that the `String` object, being `final`, *might* be optimized for faster access by the compiler (and I'm speculating) but that's all. None of the snippets will be considerable *faster* than the others once the JIT compiler kicks in, what really matters is which one is easier to read and understand.

Regarding the two other questions: the three options (four counting mine) are practically equivalent, because the JIT infrastructure will probably store the length in a register of its own for the duration of the iteration, given that it's not changing and it's being used in a loop, so there's no point in doing the compiler's work by hand. Optimize for readability, forget about early optimizations (which are the root of all evil) and in case of doubt, *profile* first and optimize later.

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be a comma between `i = 0` and `n = str.length()` rather than a semicolon?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor oops, typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

General rule of java: don't optimize before you have performance issues.

Especially in cases like this one. You can think about performance of network connection or database. These things can take few seconds.